# Max if statement based on column

Tags: if-statement, switch-statement, max, powerbi-desktop

I have week no column that came from date, based on the max week no column I am trying to get the if statement yes or no.

Example: if week number column contain from 01 to 40 so 40 is the highest week no so I would like to get the result is Yes by using calculate column otherwise no.

Week No  Deired Result
1         No
2         No
3         No
4         No
5         Yed

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer...

```
IF(MAX(Table [weekno]) =Table [weekno], "Yes", "No".
```